# Consuming REST Web Service in SAP Data Services

Tags: rest, sap-data-services

In SAP BODS, I want consuming REST Web Service in SAP Data Services using Web Service REST Datastore. I followed the instructions from this link https://blogs.sap.com/2016/06/07/consuming-rest-web-service-in-sap-data-services-using-web-service-rest-datastore/ , but when I run the execution I come across this error:

> `|Data flow DF _Oxyane_restlTransform QRY_Oxyane_rest_28-Function3` 
> `HTTP client error:<60>:<Peer certificate cannot be authenticated with given CA certificates>.`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the SSL certificate from your rest endpoint/URL. In Linux you can run the following commands from the command line.

`openssl s_client -servername <servername> -connect <servername:port> | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > <certificate_name>.crt`

Open the `<certificate_name>.crt` file generated from the command above and copy it's content.

Navigate to `$LINK_DIR/ssl/trusted_certs/` and open the `curl_cacert.pem` file, scroll to the bottom of the file and paste the the certificate you copied from the `<certificate_name>.crt` file.
Restart the job server by running the following command

`$LINK_DIR/bin/svrcfg -TSTOP && sleep 10 && $LINK_DIR/bin/svrcfg -TSTART`

finally try running the job again.

For windows please check SAP KBA 2343560